# Serialize relations in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models --> Candidate and Grade. 1 Candidate have many Grade. I want to return from rest API average grade from many grades that one Candidate can receive. How can I doing this.

**My model:**

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Grade(models.Model):
   value = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='grades')
```

My serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Candidate, Grade


class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   pk = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_pk_from_candidate')
   full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_name_from_candidate')
   grades = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='value')
   
   class Meta: 
    
      model = Candidate
 
      fields = ['pk', 'full_name', 'avg_grade', 'grades']

  
   def get_pk_from_candidate(self, candidate):
      return candidate.id

   
   def get_full_name_from_candidate(self, candidate):
      data = (candidate.first_name, candidate.last_name)
      full_name = ' '.join(data)

      return full_name
```

I want my JSON format like below:

```
{
      "pk": 3,
      "full_name": "rafał małek",
      "avg_grade": "",
      "grades": [
        12,
        4,
        13,
        5
      ]
    },
```

Comment: I tried to write method where I can calculate average but I don't know how to handle in that method my grades array

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **[SerializerMethodField()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)** and ORM's **[Aggregation(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/)** with Avg.

```py
from django.db.models import Avg
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Candidate, Grade


class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   pk = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_pk_from_candidate')
   full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_name_from_candidate')
   avg_grade = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_avg_grade')
   grades = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='value')
   
   class Meta: 
      model = Candidate
      fields = ['pk', 'full_name', 'avg_grade', 'grades']

  
   def get_pk_from_candidate(self, candidate):
      return candidate.id

   
   def get_full_name_from_candidate(self, candidate):
      data = (candidate.first_name, candidate.last_name)
      full_name = ' '.join(data)

      return full_name

   def get_avg_grade(self, candidate):
       return candidate.grades.aggregate(Avg('value'))['value__avg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`serializers.SerializerMethodField`** as

```
from django.db.models import Avg


class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_pk_from_candidate')
    full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_name_from_candidate')
    grades = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='value')
    avg_grade = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_avg_grade(self, candidate):
        return candidate.grades.aggregate(avg_value=Avg('value')).get("avg_value")

    class Meta:
        model = Candidate

        fields = ['pk', 'full_name', 'avg_grade', 'grades']

    def get_pk_from_candidate(self, candidate):
        return candidate.id

    def get_full_name_from_candidate(self, candidate):
        data = (candidate.first_name, candidate.last_name)
        full_name = ' '.join(data)

        return full_name
```